# Rotina de manutenção para limpeza em tabelas de log (sysssislog e sysdtslog90)

Tags: sql-server, log

Tenho uma base de dados SQL SERVER 2014 standard e durante o acompanhamento da base, percebi que tenho algumas tabelas do SQL que estão um pouco grandes e foi pesquisar a respeito.

As tabelas são `sysssislog` e `sysdtslog90`

Pela documentação, essas [tabelas são para log de execução de pacotes DTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186984.aspx).

Existe alguma rotina específica ou utilitário padrão para limpeza dessas tabelas ou simplesmente eu posso dar um delete por período ou mesmo um `truncate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas tabelas são usada mesmo para *logs* do SSIS e com o tempo tendem a ficar grandes. As recomendações que li [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef333ad4-d370-4cea-8055-227d402ba65b/sysssislog-maintenance?forum=sqlintegrationservices) e [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/827dad76-a410-45d6-b723-009e89854280/deleting-records-from-dbosysdtslog90?forum=sqlintegrationservices) são que você pode apagar esses logs caso não precise.

> Existe alguma rotina específica ou utilitário padrão para limpeza
>   dessas tabelas ou simplesmente eu posso dar um delete por período ou
>   mesmo um truncate?

Não me lembro de uma rotina *built-in* que limpe essas tabelas, mas você pode dar um `truncate` sem problemas. Para não ter que fazer isso manualmente você pode agendar um *job* no SQL Server Agent para fazer isso de tempos em tempos. Mais informações de como fazer isso:

- [Habilitar o SQL Server Agent](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191454(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Configurar um *job* do tipo SQL query](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/257/sql-server/criando-e-executando-jobs-no-sql-server/?trace=1519021197&source=single)